# Isotope Uncaught TypeError

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-isotope

I am currently working on developing a Wordpress theme. And i am trying to integrate Isotope into my Wordpress theme according to the following tutorial:

https://redvinestudio.com/how-to-build-isotope-portfolio-in-your-wordpress-theme/

However, i am currently struggeling with the jQuery part of the tutorial. When i look at my console, i get a log saying: "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).smartresize is not a function".

This pretty much results in my portfolio not looking anywhere near the isotope masonry layout..

So I've been looking for some solutions, and the problem might be that this tutorial was written in 2014. This was at the time Isotope V1 was out. Right now, Isotope V2 is out. So i might need to change some things in isotope.filtering.js file. But i can't really figure out what to change? I've tried to find my solution in the isotope documentation but it doesn't really help me out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/metafizzy/isotope/issues/781

`smartresize` is not included in new isotope since it's ready for responsive layout.

Check this out as well: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/appendix.html#upgrading-from-v1 and this: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html#isfitwidth

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the useful links! Trying some of that stuff right now! Will let you know if it helped me out.

Comment: It shouldn't be hard. If you have multiple isotope containers on your page, just call them with `$('.container').each(function(){$(this).isotope({//isotope options here})});`, and set the `itemSelector` to your image, that is defined in percentage with `display:inline-block;`, and the outer container to `font-size:0;`. That way you'll assure your images will be neatly aligned even before isotope kicks in. `$('.container')` is your image container ofc. The width in percentage will assure responsiveness (that and media queries) :)

Comment: Your `.futr-portfolio .portfolio-item` has `float` and `display:inline-block`. Which makes no sense, since `float` elements are not in the page flow, and are `block` by default. So remove the float, and all should work even on refresh with ctrl+R :)

Comment: Hmm, this is weird. I removed the float and tried both `display: inline-block` and `display: inline`. But still, my elements don't position correctly on CTRL + R refresh. I tried to change the hierachy of the JS files, loaded my `isotope-filtering.js` in front of `isotope.js` and vice-versa. But that dind't seem to make a difference either...

Comment: Odd, `inline-block` should do the trick. Don't align them `inline`, this isn't good way to do it. Try using [imagesLoaded](http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/) to wait for images to be loaded, then to fire the masonry after they are loaded. Also `inline-block` :D

Comment: Thanks alot for the help man! That imagesloaded did indeed seem to the trick. Again, thanks alot for the help!

Comment: No problem, happy to help :D